# NodeJs multer upload file

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I want to create a post method to upload details and image in to the server
code :

```
var express = require('express');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const AdminLog = require('../model/adminSchema')
const Product = require('../model/addVehicle')
const path = require('path')
const { Manufacturer } = require('../model/manufac');
const { VehicleModel } = require('../model/model')
const multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();
// const upload = multer();






const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  // destination: (req, file, cb) => {
  //   cb(null, './uploads/'); // The directory where uploaded images will be stored
  // },
  destination: './upload/',
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' +Data.now()+path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage:storage });











router.post('/admin/login', async function(req, res, next) {
  const {name,password} = req.body;
  const adminD = await AdminLog.findOne({name});
  if(!adminD){
    console.log("Wrong");
    return res.send("Access Denied!!")
  }
  else{
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password,adminD.password);
  if(!validPassword){
    console.log("Wrong password");
    return res.send('Password is incorrect');
  }
  console.log("okk");

  res.send("Login successful");
}});

// router.post('/admin/products', async (req, res) => {
//   const product = new Product(req.body);
//   await product.save();
//   res.send(product);
// });


// POST route to create a new product with an image
router.post('/admin/products', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      name,
      manufacturer,
      model,
      price,
      description,
      quantity,
    } = req.body;

    const imagePath = req.file.path; // The path to the uploaded image

    const newProduct = new Product({
      name,
      manufacturer,
      model,
      price,
      image: imagePath, // Save the image path in the database
      description,
      quantity,
    });

    await newProduct.save();
    res.status(201).json(newProduct);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});




// router.post('/admin/products', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
//   try {
//     const { name, manufacturer, model, price, description, quantity } = req.body;
//     const newProduct = new Product({
//       name,
//       manufacturer,
//       model,
//       price,
//       description,
//       quantity,
//       image: {
//         data: req.file.buffer.toString('base64'),
//         contentType: req.file.mimetype
//       }
//     });
//     await newProduct.save();
//     console.log("Okk")
//     res.json({ message: 'Product uploaded successfully' });
//   } catch (error) {
//     console.error(error);
//     res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while uploading the product' });
//   }
// });

router.put('/admin/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);

  // Update fields from req.body
  product.name = req.body.name;
  product.manufacturer = req.body.manufacturer;
  product.model = req.body.model;
  product.price = req.body.price;

  // Save the updated product
  await product.save();

  res.send(product);
});

router.get('/admin/products', async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Product.find({});
  res.send(products);
});

router.delete('/admin/products/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const deletedUser = await Product.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id);
res.send(deletedUser);
});



router.get('/admin/manufacturers', async (req, res) => {
  // Fetch all manufacturers from your database and send them as a response
  // This is just a placeholder. Replace it with your actual logic.
  const manufacturers = await Manufacturer.find({});
  res.json(manufacturers);
});

// Route to get all models
router.get('/admin/models', async (req, res) => {
  // Fetch all models from your database and send them as a response
  // This is just a placeholder. Replace it with your actual logic.
  const models = await VehicleModel.find({});
  res.json(models);
});
module.exports = router;
```

But it is showing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
at C:\Users\user\Documents\MERN\week7\backend\routes\index.js:76:32
can anyone find the error.I want to upload product image from page but it is showing the error above.

Comment: Your `req.file.path` is where you should start debugging. This is `undefined` because the `req` object does not have a `file` property. That suggests the upload has not saved. Make sure your folder on the server is called `upload` and that your form input that submits the file for upload is `name="image"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.